# Outlook Mac: Autofit from Layout tab

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

I am using Outlook Version 16 for Mac.
How do I Autofit an excel table I just pasted? I do not see the Layout tab below. The excel table is not copying its original form.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/resize-a-table-column-or-row-9340d478-21be-4392-81cf-488f7bbd6715

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the article you provide, I noticed that it's available for Outlook for Windows. And I have done a lot of test but didn't find it in Outlook for mac. I'm afraid it's a feature in Outlook for windows.

According to your description, I noticed that "The excel table is not copying its original form." As I know, when pasting the content, whether you're using New Outlook or Legacy Outlook, there will be a window prompting which format to paste. And if you choose "Keep Source Formatting", the original form will be pasted.
[image]

On the other hand, you can also enable the option as shown in the below figure. For more information about pasting content in Outlook for mac, please refer to: [Paste text and images into your message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-email-messages-in-outlook-for-mac-cb35806b-4174-41d2-9cba-b6b624d988b3#:%7E:text=Paste%20text%20and%20images%20into%20your%20message).

New Outlook:
[image]

Legacy Outlook:

[image]

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.